# Sage python3 jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, sage

I am fairly new to Sage but I have been using python and jupyter for a while now. I need help in figuring out how to start a sage jupyter notebook with python 3 as this command in terminal `sage -n jupyter` opens a jupyter notebook with Sage kernel but i think it by default uses python 2.
I need to use python 3 because I need to work with urls, specifically  `import urllib.request` as this currently gives me error `ImportError No modules named request` while using Sage kernel in jupyter notebook whereas with python 3 kernel it works fine.

Comment: What is the version of `sage` you're using? You can know that by typing `sage -v` in the terminal

Comment: Sage 8.1 , I know this is not the latest but this was the one install by using sudo apt install sage. I have Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: And that's the problem... SageMath has been running on top of Python 2 since the beginning, until version 8.9, released in September 2019. Starting from Sage 9.0, released in January 2020, SageMath is running on top of Python 3.

Comment: try `sudo apt install sagemath-common`

Comment: after installing sagemath-common should i be able to run python3 with `sage -n jupyter`

Comment: Let's try and see :D

Comment: after installing , the `sage --version` is still 8.1 and the jupyter notebook still uses python 2.7

Comment: try to uninstall the first installation, try `sudo apt purge sage`

Comment: unable to locate package sage

Comment: Try deleting the `sage` folder, run `which sage` ... mine is `/usr/bin/sage`

Comment: really interesting this, `which sage` gives `/usr/bin/sage` but when i try to delete it there is no such file or directory and i even checked in /usr/bin there is no sage but still i'm able to run sage

Comment: close your terminal and open it again :D

Comment: Did it work now?

Comment: still the same ! is there a way to install sage 9 on ubuntu 18.04 without sudo command line

Comment: You can try [this](https://mohdalmiealias.wordpress.com/2020/04/24/installing-sagemath-version-9-in-ubuntu-18-04/)